# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itx}}{(1+x^{c})^{k+1}} \, \mathrm{d}x $?

Tags: characteristic-functions

I was calculating a characteristic function and I couldn't compute this integral: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itx}}{(1+x^{c})^{k+1}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
Where $k,c>0$, any hint would be of great help.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{(1+x^2)^2} = \frac{\pi}{2 e} \approx $ [Euler--Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

Comment: Isn't the caracteristic function supposed to be a function of $t$?

Comment: Have you tried contour integration?