# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^{c})^{k+1}} \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: integration

I'm having trouble integrating this: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^{c})^{k+1}} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
Where $c,k>0$. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: Mathematica says, under suitable convergence hypothesis ($\Re(c)>0$ and $\Re(c(k+1))>1$), that your integral equals
$$\frac{\Gamma\left( 1+ \frac{1}{c}\right) \Gamma\left(-\frac{1+c(k+1)}{c}\right)}{\Gamma(-(k+1))}.$$

Or do you need a hand-calculation?

Comment: This is a very difficult problem, and has no general approach. At least, are $c,k$ positive integers or they may be any real number?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano, I need hand-calculation, but it's better to know the results so I know what I should have.

Comment: @Crostul, I don't know if they're real or integers, the only thing I know is that they're positive.

Comment: Well, then I also signal, if you do not already know it, the page http://dlmf.nist.gov/5 . And observe that only positive doesn't make it always convergent. Good luck!

Comment: @Crostul "This is a very difficult problem, and has no general approach." Hmmm... For every $c$ positive (otherwise the integral diverges), the change of variable $$t=\frac1{1+x^c}$$ does the job neatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x^{c} = z$,
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} (1+x^{c})^{-k-1} \mathrm{d} x & = \frac{1}{c} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} z^{\frac{1}{c}-1} (1+z)^{-k-1} \mathrm{d} z \\
& = \frac{1}{c} \mathrm{B}\left(\frac{1}{c}, k+1 - \frac{1}{c}\right) \\
& = \frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{c} \right)\Gamma\left( k+1-\frac{1}{c} \right)}{c\Gamma(k+1)}
\end{align}

Comment: Isn't the beta function integrable only on $[0,1]$?

Comment: No, see http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12

Comment: @ poweierstrass, can you help me find this?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1898465/how-to-calculate-int-0-infty-fraceitx1xck1-mathrmd

Comment: That integral is related to the inverse Fourier transform. My knowledge of Fourier transforms is insufficient to answer the question via this method. Also, as a commentator noted, one could try contour integration but this will be messy. I have added an up vote to the question.